# Email Body Blank/Empty When Mail Is Sent from Draft

Tags: visual-c++, ms-office, outlook-addin, office-addins, mapi

We are facing an issue where, Outlook send an empty body email when the mail is sent from Drafts folder. This issue started after updating the outlook to latest build 2311 (Build 17029.20108).
We have an Outlook Plugin developed in Visual Studio, C++, MAPI.  This plugin connects the Outlook to server.
While checking the logs I have observed that when send mail from Drafts folder, the first call comes from Outlook is below one.

```
IMessage::DeleteProps() ->
  0 PR_RTF_COMPRESSED                         PT_BINARY 
  1 PR_HTML                                             PT_STRING8 
  2 PR_BODY                                             PT_UNICODE 
  3 PR_RTF_IN_SYNC                                 PT_BOOLEAN
```

**The detailed scenario is as below:**

1. Open the outlook.
2. Open new email compose windows
3. Write a subject and body, include TO list and save it to draft folder.
4. Now send email from draft folder.
5. Email gets sent properly but in SENT folder as well as at recipient end it doesn't have BODY part. Thought it has Subject.

Configuration:
Windows 10, x64
Outlook 365 Version 2311 (Build 17029.20108) And Version 2311 (Build 17029.20068)

Any known issue from Outlook side, any work around? Any pointers?

Thanks in advance,
Mahesh Amarelia

Tried below things which didn't work:

1. Disabling plugin and enabling it again.
2. Repairing outlook
3. Re creating user profile.

Comment: So what is deleting all these body properties? What does your code do?